# File path without domain name from wp_get_attachment_url()

Tags: wordpress, codex

wp_get_attachment_url() process full file path like

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/aura.mp3
```

I want the url without `http://example.com/`
So, I want above example as `wp-content/uploads/2014/12/aura.mp3` instead of `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/aura.mp3`. How to do it?

Comment: I want it for getid3 coz getid3 don't support remote URL

Comment: please see here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144409/how-to-get-list-of-paths-not-urls-for-an-image

Comment: @gauravkumar I am not a pro.. My files are mp3. so image bissue is confusing\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can really easily [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by */* and then take the part with index 3. Example

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url(id); //id is file's id
$urllocal = explode(site_url(), $url)[1]; //output local path
```

Comment: it only returns wp-content, not full file path

Comment: Are you sure you tried the latest version? I had to fix it after I posted it.

Comment: I used this `$mp3remoteurl = wp_get_attachment_url($_GET["id"]);
$mp3localurl = ''.explode("/", $mp3remoteurl)[1].'/'.explode("/", $mp3remoteurl)[2].'/'.explode("/", $mp3remoteurl)[3].'/'.explode("/", $mp3remoteurl)[4].'/'.explode("/", $mp3remoteurl)[5].'';` to get wp-content/uploads/2014/12/aura.mp3 but this is not the proper way. Ain't I right?

Comment: Yea. wp 4.1 - latest version and it is in localhost

Comment: @SahriarSaikat: Well, it is one way to do it, but not the prettiest for sure. That is why I changed my code to work with the server name when exploding: explode("example.com/", $url)[1];

Comment: @SahriarSaikat: Great, I'm sorry for the struggle caused by my edits. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the WordPress way using WordPress functions (avoid hacking):

```
$fullsize_path = get_attached_file( $attachment_id ); // Full path
$filename_only = basename( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) ); // Just the file name
```

WordPress has tons of functions, so first try to find the function on the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's function [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
         $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( 9 ); //ID of your attachment
         $my_image_url = explode('/',$image_url,4);
         echo $my_image_url[3];
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. by the way, I got the proper answer.

Comment: Actually use of `site_url()` is pretty good.It did not come in my mind :)

Comment: Yup ..Happy Coding ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `implode` your entire url on `/` and `array_slice` from the end, then implode it back in on `/`.

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url($item->ID); //id is file's id
$url_relative = implode(array_slice(explode('/', $url),-3,3),'/');
//Returns: 2019/08/image.jpg
```

That way if your WordPress is on a subdomain or localhost or the images are on S3 it won't crash.

Comment: That's a really old question you have answered. If I am to answer my 5 years old question now, I would say `str_replace('http://example.com/', '', wp_get_attachment_url($item->ID));` is a nice choice.